# Почему wmic не удаляет office 2013 и возвращает значение 1603?

Tags: windows, wmi, office365

Здравствуйте, есть такая задача – для ряда удаленных ОС выполнить:

```
wmic /node:"hotname" product where name="Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

Проблема в том, что программа возвращает значение 1603. Обычно это указывает на отсутствие привилегий. Но моя учетная запись вне всяких сомнений имеет достаточные полномочия для выполнения заказанной операции + я повысил привилегии с помощью UAC перед выполнением. Также я пытался выполнить команду, в то время когда в обще отсутствовали какие–либо интерактивные сеансы.

Comment: Попробуй по UUID удалять. Та же ошибка будет? Типа `wmic product where identifyingnumber="{1845470B-EB14-4ABC-835B-E36C693DC07D}" call uninstall`

Comment: wmic /node:"hostname" product where identifyingnumber="{90150000-0011-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}" call uninstall 
Идет выполнение (\\hostname\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber="{90150000-0011-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}",Name="Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013",Version="15.0.4569.1506")->Uninstall()

Метод успешно вызван.

Параметры вывода:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
 ReturnValue = 1603;
};

Comment: То есть такая же.

Comment: Другое приложение удаляется по имени без проблем.

Comment: Я так со скайпом ковырялся. Скайп по имени удалялся, а что-то другое не хотело. И я пришёл к идентификаторам. У меня они точно работали.